# Help proving that $\lim f(x,y)=|x|^{a}|y|^{b} / (|x|^{c} + |y|^{d}) = 0$ if $a/c + b/d >1$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

First, $a/c + b/d >1$ is the same as $a + b > c + d$.

Next, my plan is to use squeeze theorem. Find $B(x,y)$ such that $|f(x,y)-0|<B(x,y)$, where $\lim B(x,y) = 0$.

What I have so far:
\begin{align*} 
\frac{|x|^{a}\cdot|y|^{b}}{|x|^{c}+|y|^{d}} &\leq \frac{|x+y|^{a}\cdot|y+x|^{b}}{ |x|^{c}  + |y|^{d}}\\[1em] &\leq \frac{(|x|^{a}+|y|^{a})\cdot(|y|^{b}+|x|^{b})}{|x|^{c}  + |y|^{d}}\\[1em]&=\frac{(|x|+|y|)^{a+b}}{|x|^{c}  + |y|^{d}}.
\end{align*}
I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute $|x|=v^{\frac{1}{c}},  |y| =w^{\frac{1}{d}}$ then we have $$0\leq \frac{|x|^a |y|^b}{|x|^c +|y|^d }  =\frac{v^{\frac{a}{c}} w^{\frac{b}{d}}}{v+w} \leq \frac{M^{\frac{a}{c}} M^{\frac{b}{d}}}{M} =M^{\frac{a}{c} +\frac{b}{d} -1}$$ where $M=\max\{v, w\}.$